# what is this htaccess rule actually doing

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this condition and rule and want to know what actually is going on here

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitepages/newversion/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[?|&])page=dynamicpage
RewriteRule ^sitepages/newversion/(.*)$ /pages/oldversion/$1 [L]
```

Also very interested in a detail explaination of this line

```
RewriteRule ^sitepages/newversion/(.*)$ /pages/oldversion/$1 [L]
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitepages/newversion/
```

If the request URL starts with "/sitepages/newversion/",

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[?|&])page=dynamicpage
```

and the query string contains "page=dynamicpage",

```
RewriteRule ^sitepages/newversion/(.*)$ /pages/oldversion/$1 [L]
```

then take the part of the URL after "sitepages/newversion/" and redirect the request to "/pages/oldversion/(the rest of the url)".

For example:

```
http://domain.com/sitepages/newversion/someleaf?page=dynamicpage
```

will get redirected to

```
http://domain.com/pages/oldversion/someleaf?page=dynamicpage
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your rule can be rewritten better as this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)page=dynamicpage(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitepages/newversion/(.*)$ /pages/oldversion/$1 [L,NC]
```

Now for explanation part.

- `RewriteCond` is matching a URI with query parameter `page=dynamicpage`
- `RewriteRule` is matching a URI with pattern `sitepages/newversion/(.*)$` which will match `/sitepages/newversion/abc123` or `/sitepages/newversion/foobar`
- `(.*)` is capturing group to populate `$1` with the value `abc123` in my first example.
- In target we use `/pages/oldversion/$1` that will become `/pages/oldversion/abc123` for same example.
- `NC` flag is for no case comparison.
- `L` flag is for `Last` that makes `mod_rewrite` run the rewrite loop again.

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)